# Can SQLite subqueries contain ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, subquery

I have the following SQL that selects discussion forum threads with accompanying info about the first/last posts, number of posts and the user who started it:

```
SELECT forum_threads.*, 
       users.displayname as cc_username, 
       coalesce(count(forum_posts.id),0) AS cc_postCount,
       (select id from forum_posts where threadId=forum_threads.id order by tsCreate asc limit 1) as cc_firstPostId,
       (select id from forum_posts where threadId=forum_threads.id order by tsCreate desc limit 1) as cc_lastPostId,
       (select tsCreate from forum_posts where threadId=forum_threads.id order by tsCreate desc limit 1) as cc_tsLatest
FROM forum_threads
LEFT JOIN forum_posts ON forum_posts.threadId = forum_threads.id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = forum_threads.userId
GROUP BY forum_threads.id
ORDER BY forum_posts.tsCreate DESC
```

It seems to work fine, but I just read on [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_sub_queries.htm) that SQLite subqueries cannot contain `ORDER BY`. Mine do, and they work.

How come they work? Was I just lucky, and should I structure my query in some other way?

Comment: You can use ORDER BY and LIMIT in a subquery, but you already know that because your code works. What is also wrong in that page is the rule: *BETWEEN operator cannot be used with a subquery; .....*

Comment: I have yet to see a tutorialspoint article on SQLite that isn't full of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of subquery you are generating is called a *scalar subquery* in SQL.  This is a subquery that returns one column and at most one row.  It calculates a single value and can be used in the `select` and `where` clauses, for instance.

The [documentation for expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) describes scalar subqueries:

> Subquery Expressions
>
> . . .
>
> A subquery that returns a single column is a scalar subquery and can be used most anywhere. A subquery that returns two or more columns is a row value subquery and can only be used as the operand of a comparison operator.

There is no distinction made regarding the use of `order by`.

Actually, your type of subquery is really a *scalar correlated subquery*, but the same reasoning applies.

I should note that the syntax diagram for expressions in SQLite appears to be missing scalar subqueries.  So the documentation explains it.  I think this is a bug in the documentation.

Although you can use tutorials for guidance, if you really want to know what a database does, the check the documentation for that database.